# Exact day (in words of) the week in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

[image]

In this case I am trying to extract
 - The first day of the month from col2, record 201
 - The day of the week from col2, record 201 
 - The last day of the previous month from col2, record 201

My Codes:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, 1/19/2012), 0) AS StartOfMonth
FROM SpecialMenu

SELECT CONVERT(Varchar, Col2) FROM SpecialMenu
WHere col1 = 201

SELECT DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(@Year) - 2012) * 12) + MONTH(@Year), -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @date datetime ='1/19/2012 08:00 AM'
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @date), 0) AS StartOfMonth ,
datepart(dw,@date) as dayofweek, 
DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@date)), @date) lastdayofprevmonth
```

Comment: THANK YOU Radar. I'll look into separating the code.. I meant each one starting with a dash as separate queries.